# list the "middle" part of an input in the end of the output in awk

Tags: awk

This is regarding a hostfile.

INPUT:

```
1.2.3.4 foooo00001 foo001 # AIX bar0003 NOSLS NOSLS NOCOMMENT
2.3.4.1 foooo00002 foo002 fooo0002 # Linux bar0003 NOSLS NOSLS NOCOMMENT
```

OUTPUT:

```
echo "$INPUT" | awk '{print $(NF-3)";"$2";"$1";"$(NF-2)";"$(NF-1)}'
bar0003;foooo00001;1.2.3.4;NOSLS;NOSLS
bar0003;foooo00002;2.3.4.1;NOSLS;NOSLS
```

but we need this output:

```
echo "$INPUT" | awk SOMEMAGIC
bar0003;foooo00001;1.2.3.4;NOSLS;NOSLS;foo001
bar0003;foooo00002;2.3.4.1;NOSLS;NOSLS;foo002;fooo0002
```

**Question:** How can we modify the awk to append the aliases (amount could vary, a host can have zero, one, two, etc. aliases)?

Space is the delimiter and the aliases are after the hostnames and always ends with "#".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like `awk` try

```
echo "$INPUT" | \
awk -v OFS=';' '
{for(i=4;$i!="#";i++)
     $3=$3 OFS $i
 print $(NF-3),$2,$1,$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$3}'
```

Same you can do with GNU `sed`

```
echo "$INPUT" | \
sed -r 's/(\S*)( \S* )(.*) # \S* (\S*)( .* )\S*/\4\2\1\5\3/;s/ /;/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
echo "$INPUT" | awk '{ for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) { if ($i ~ /#/) { pos = i; break; } } } { for (i = 3; i < pos; i++) s = s";"$i; print $(NF-3)";"$2";"$1";"$(NF-2)";"$(NF-1)s }'
```